# Traffic Intersection Simulation using Multi Threading Algorithm

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, synchronization, deadlock, semaphore

This is a interview Question which was asked and wanted to find an efficient solution.

### Problem

Consider a intersection of four roads as shown in the diagram. Each road is defined to have a direction. How would you solve the problem so as to **improve the traffic condition** and **avoid deadlocks**.

1. the intersection is divided into four quadrants [shown in yellow].
2. Cars enter the intersection at random from the four direction [0,1,2,3]
3. At the intersection each car can make a single move. the three possible moves are

   1. Go left
   2. Go straight
   3. Go right

e.g :

> if a car enters from **direction 2** and wants to take a left turn. it should pass through
>   **quandrant 2** , **quandrant 1** and finally **quandrant 0**

[image]

### Semi complete solution

Each **quadrant** marked in yellow has a semaphore associated with it.
What I imagined was a 2 phase protocol wherein each car would

1. get list of quadrants it will pass through
2. lock each of the quadrants starting from the last quadrant

   3. In the above example the car from **direction 2** would lock **quadrant 0**, **quadrant 1** and then **quadrant 2**.
3. Move through the intersection
4. Release the locks acquired.

   3. The locks are released in the same order. **quadrant 0**, **quandrant 1** and the **quandrant 2**

*However the above solution is less than optimal as it results in a deadlock.*

### My Question is

1. What other /better way can this be achieved?
2. Can I implement this using a semaphore in C?

   2. If not what synchronization method should I be looking at?

### Updates

1. I want a solution which allows multiple cars can enter the *intersection* and still avoid deadlock as well as collision.Having a single lock on the entire intersection would be less than optimized.

Comment: Semaphores are needed if the processes generating each car movement are separate. If you are simulating the whole thing in a single program you wouldn't need semaphores, just flags should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to implement a solution in C using the following logic (The actual implementation used semaphores for each of the quadrant).

The solution I mentioned in the question was partially correct however I was experiencing deadlock due to the matter in which locks were made.
I was able to solve the issue by assigning priority to the locks.
The locks are gained by locking highest priority lock first.
Following is a pseudo-code algorithm used by each of the car:

**Assumptions:**

1. Each quadrant has a lock associated with it.
2. Each lock has an associated priority. The priorities are as follows

> **Priority(Lock_0) < Priority(Lock_1) < Priority(Lock_2) < Priority(Lock_3)**
> *where Lock_x is the lock for Quadrant x

**Algorithm**

1. Each car gets list of quadrants it will pass through
2. Lock each of the quadrants starting from the quadrant with highest priority.

   e.g:  In the above example the car from direction 2 taking a left turn would lock **quadrant 2**, **quadrant 0** and then **quadrant 1**.
3. Move through the intersection
4. Release the locks acquired.

   e.g: In the above example the locks are released in the same order. **quadrant 2**, **quandrant 1** and the **quandrant 0**

Comment: One optimization is that I'm pretty sure you can unlock a quadrant after you leave the quadrant.  You don't have to wait to leave the intersection before you unlock them all.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution (as suggested in step 2) does not *avoid* deadlock.

Consider the case when from the four streets there are cars wanting to turn to their left. Then all the cars start locking different cuadrants:

from direction 0, it locks cuadrant 2.
from direction 1, it locks cuadrant 3.
from direction 2, it locks cuadrant 0.
from direction 3, it locks cuadrant 1.
-- deadlock --

You could avoid the deadlock by having a mutex shared by the four directions.

Comment: Having a single mutex for all the quadrants is the most simple however a *trivial* and least optimized solution which would badly create a bottleneck at the intersection. Sorry I wanted a something where in the two cars could enter the intersection , but still avoid a collision. I shall update the question to include this!

Comment: I agree the solution suggested by Gray is more natural, and for an interview question is a very good answer, but is it more efficient? To find out, you need to analyse your traficc patterns: what happens if traffic is 95% coming from 2 and want to go to 3, and 5% is coming from 0 and want to go to 3? the solution degenerates to the one with a big shared mutex. Is it fair? No: destination streets with lower cuadrant numbers will be more time blocked than higher number cuadrant, so cars from street 3 that want to turn right to 2 will get more priority than those coming from 0 to turn to 3.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your "last quadrant" locking order is last that it sees as it moves through the intersection?

I think you can change your algorithm to always lock the quadrants in numerical order -- unlocking if any is already locked and retry.  The car would have to lock its complete path before driving through the intersection and unlocking.  For example, if a car wanted to go from path 1 to 2 it would lock first quadrant 0 and then 3.  If it wanted to go from path 3 to 1 then it would lock 2 first and 3 next.

I think that solves the deadlock issue because each thread is locking in the same order.  Using your Deadlock happens when someone locks 3 0 1 and someone while someone is locking 1 2 3.

So the complete task list would be:

1. It tries to lock its path in quadrant numerical order (0, 1, 2, 3).  If this is C then I'd use `` `pthread_mutex_trylock() `` with a lock for each quadrant.
2. If it finds that a quadrant is locked it unlocks the ones that it locked, sleeps a random amount of time, and starts over.
3. If it locks its complete path it then can traverse the path.
4. Once it's traveled through a quadrant it can unlock it safely.  It doesn't have to wait to go out the other side before it unlocks.

As you mention, what it can't do is lock it's first quadrant, enter that quadrant and then try to lock the next one in the path.  That would lead to deadlock or gridlock in this case.

Comment: Each car here **IS** locking all the quadrants that will come in its way before entering any of the quadrants. Hence the two phase lock phase. What would be **an appropriate locking primitive** to use if I want to check if the quadrant is locked and sleep randomly if it is and then continue to do the same till i acquire the lock. Also wont this locking and releasing locks generate starvation of the car?

Comment: If you are using C then I'd use `pthread_mutex_trylock`.  Again, you would have to lock _all_ of the quadrants before entering the intersection.  If any trylock fails then you unlock all your locks, sleep, and try again.  If the random sleep works against a car then it could wait longer than it should but practically it would be most optimal.  I don't understand the "two phase lock" comment.

Answer (score 0):

You may actually not need semaphores to implement a solution.. 
the problem is not really about resource control (not need to lock quadrants)
is about resource scheduling..

lets assume that motion/time occurs in discrete steps

to know when to start moving your car you have to predict if the quadrant will be in use or not when you will need it in the future.. for that, as each car comes into the intersection it should describe its intent.. using a queue of steps.. example:

lets have a queue with 1 row for each quadrant

```
 T 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
 0|
 1|
 2|
 3|
```

when car 1 comes from the bottom(2) he will use (Quadrants: 2 1 0) so he reserves the quadrants

```
 T 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
 0|    1
 1|  1 
 2|1
 3|
```

if car number 2 comes from the right on tick 2 and wants to go forward (Q: 1 0)

```
 T 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
 0|   2*1
 1| 2*1 
 2|1
 3|
```

we have a crash, so each car will have try to mark is intention only if all the quadrants that it needs are empty.. if not it will slide the intention by 1 frame and try again.. in this case the schedule of the car 2 would be

```
 T 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
 0|    1 2
 1|  1 2
 2|1
 3|
```

if no conflict occurs the motion can be scheduled as soon as possible, if car 3 comes at time frame 2 from top(0) and wants to go bottom (Q:0 3) he can start immediately. because none of the quadrants that it as intention of using, will be occupied when he will have the need to use it

```
 T 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
 0|  3 1 2
 1|  1 2
 2|1
 3|    3
```

this is the general method.. for specific implementation there will be variations..
if you to have threads (one for each car) you may need to synchronize their access to the queue.. but that is only to synchronize data access **not** the intersection logic

and if the motion steps are not discrete units, a queue frame will have to represent X seconds of animation..